# Declaring global char array in C header file

Tags: c, global-variables

I have a header file that contains all the string command as shown below:

```
const char AT_RSSI[] = "ATRSSI\r\n";
const char AT_DEVICE_SECURITY[] = "ATDS";
```

But, using this method each of char sentence is appended with \0 at the end and this is inconvenient as I need to remove 1 char, each time I use the sizeof() method

There is another solution is to use

```
//header file
extern const char *AT_RSSI;

//some.c
const char *AT_RSSI = "ATRSSI\r\n";
```

and declare it in one of the .c file, but I do not like this approach. I want all my constant variable to be declared in the header file

May I know how can I declare a constant global variable char array that can be included in various **.c** file?

Comment: What are you doing that you want things that look like strings but aren't null-terminated, and you also want to obtain the length of said not-strings with `sizeof` rather than `strlen`?!?!

Comment: @Hurkyl yes, i could use that strlen

Comment: At the very least, you need to read [How do I use `extern` to share variables between source files in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204)  Most particularly, you cannot reliably initialize the variables in the header — not simply.  If you do, the header can only be used by one source file in your program.  Using `char *` instead of arrays simply wastes space storing the pointers.  And it doesn't lose the terminating null byte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem of the first piece of code is, you are putting **definitions** in a header file, which would lead to multiple definition error if the header file is included by multiple `.c` files.

In general, put **definitions** only in a `.c` file, and put their **declarations** in a header.

That means, put this in a `.c` file:

```
const char AT_DEVICE_SECURITY[] = "ATDS";
```

and this in the header:

```
extern const char AT_DEVICE_SECURITY[];
```

Comment: thanks! so it is a bad idea to define my global variable in a header and included in multi C files?

Comment: i tried it before i dont get any error linking, but if i would use const char *AT_DEVICE_SECURITY = "ATDS"; i would get error linking,

Comment: @Tim: you may just be getting lucky.  The standard requires a single definition; including the header in more than one source file gives multiple definitions.  A linker might be prepared to overlook that — but it is unlikely.  Which platform are you on?  Which compiler and linker are you using?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i am using IAR linker for stm32, this code is mainly for embedded system, alright i will change the way i decalre my varibale! thnks! :)